# get() method in jCarousel fails in IE9

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jcarousel

I'm trying to make the items I add to a jcarousel object clickable by getting the item returned from the add() method (which it gets using the get() method) and adding a click event handler to it, like so:

```
for(n = 0; n < response.link_colors.length; n++) {
    item = carousel.add(n + 1, '<div style="background-color: ' + response.link_colors[n] + '; width: 75px; height: 75px;">&nbsp;</div>' );
    makeClickable(item, response.link_colors[n], 'linkcolor');
}

function makeClickable(item, selection, setting) {
    item.attr("sel", selection);

    item.click(function() { 
        eval("selections." + setting + " = $(this).attr('sel');");
        if(setting == 'layout') {
            $('#template_preview').show();
            $('#extracted_selections').show();
        }
        reloadFrame();
    }); 
}
```

This works as expected in Chrome, Firefox, etc. But IE9 tells me that the item being returned is not an object, so the attr() method is invalid.

Looking at the jCarousel code, I see this for the get method:

```
    get: function(i) {
        return $('>.jcarousel-item-' + i, this.list);
    },
```

Looks pretty straightforward. I've confirmed there's an LI element with the appropriate class name (jcarousel-item-1, for example) but even the `this.list` object it references, which gets created by the jcarousel constructor, appears to be invalid according to IE9.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some further research, I realized that I was not declaring the item variable outside of the function using `var item;` like I thought I had been doing. That fixed it in all versions of IE. So, let this be a lesson to all of you (but, especially me) - declare your variables, kids! And drink your Ovaltine.